# Typescript syntax explanation

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I am learning angular via the Tour of Heroes tutorial, I was wondering can someone explain this syntax

```
getHeroes(): Hero[] {
  return HEROES;
}
```

Why it is the getHeroes() method : to the Hero array and then return Heroes

Comment: This is a bit ambiguous. See [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to ask good questions which have a high probability of being answered. But in this case it's just saying that the _type_ of the result returned by the `getHeroes` method is an array of `Hero` objects.

Answer (score 1):

`getHeroes` method has a return type of `Hero[]`(An array of Objects of type `Hero`)

In TypeScript you tell about the type of a particular variable, property or method by:

```
variableName: Variable Type
```

So say for example:

```
add(x: number, y: number): number {
  return x + y;
}
```

Here we're defining a method named `add` that accepts two arguments, x and y. Both these arguments are of type nummber. And the `add` method also returns a number.